# ionic2: opacity of inside list not allowed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2: I want to make a modal which has a bottom list that contains some elements and take height 45% in bottom, and top list which take height 55% and should have opacity, but I can't apply opacity to top div only, I should apply to all page containing the bottom div, this is my code

```css
ion-content {
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
}
#topDiv {
    height: 55%;
}
#bottomList {
    height: 45%;
}
```

```html
<ion-content no-padding no-margin>
    <ion-list id="topDiv" (click)="dismissModal()">
    </ion-list>
    <ion-list no-lines no-padding no-margin id="bottomList">
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I want the first div to has opacity, what should I do?

Comment: `#topDiv {
    height: 55%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}`
Doesn't that work?

Comment: @robbannn no, opacity doesn't allowed to children div, it is only allowed for parent div

Comment: Thats strange, works for me.

Comment: @robbannn this page above works as a modal in another page I want the height div to be transparent to the another page but with opacity and that doesn't occures